# Volume godrays way too noisy

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I've been trying to make godrays but they take a lot of samples in my scene. It's an interior and I wanted to have some god rays from the windows, I know volumetrics are expensive, but is there a way to have more samples on the volume instead of spending it in everything else? There used to be the branched path tracing, which would be so so so useful right now, but they removed it. I tried more/less bounces, increasing the step rate and max step rates, and other stuff, but none helped.

Here's an image og the result with 15360 with a noise threshold of 0.005, also tried it with no noise threshold, and it didn't help. Step rate 0.01,  max steps 4096,  volume sampling: multiple importance,  interpolation: linear,  Homogenous
[image: Image of a very noisy god ray]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to light a dark room with one light source through a window and with a volume shader. Have you tried using [portals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/light_settings.html#area-lights) to help guide the light paths and reduce noise?

Comment: @L0Lock, yeah, there are portals in the windows, everything else is decently noise-free, except the volume

Comment: I'd like to see the scene and check different things - and I guess I'm not the only one. Could you please go to file > external data > pack all into .blend, then file > save as > open the sidebar and enable compression before saving a copy of your file, send that over [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can dig in?